# Need Information on UserInterface Creator in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am looking for a `UIPainter` (VW) like tool in `Pharo`. I see that `Glamour` has some examples in it, but I am not able to get Glamour on to the Pharo2.0 image. It would be great if I could get some suggestions.

Comment: I don't know any similar tool for Glamour. Where did you see that?

Comment: Yes you are right. Glamour dont have the tool but what i was talking was that it has some pre assembled widget examples , like tables, lists trees etc, which i believe could be tweaked to suit our requirements. At least want to investigate the possibilities of that. Always if the giants are willing to lend the shoulder then standing on it is much practical than to pose as an ugly giant myself. Also in pharo1.4 i loaded Glamour and found it interesting , but still not sure to proceed with it or not.

Comment: I am also interested in https://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/trac/SqueakCommunityProjects/wiki/designer. it look great...and will have to consider these two and reach a conclusion. Also Janko Mivšek has mentioned, may be something greater will come out of the GSOC. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such tool yet but a Google Summer of Code project is proposed:  http://gsoc2013.esug.org/projects/uipainter.

Answer (score 0):

Getting Glamour on Pharo 2.0 is done easiest by just downloading the Moose development image. There it is included.

Though after 15 years of Delphi and Interface Builder I really have to ask: what is the point of an UIPainter?